# Choosing 5 randomly ordered divs out of 15 divs

Tags: html

thank you for reading. I am completely a beginner to coding world, so I cannot even provide the source I have right now.

I have total 15 projects with 1 picture and little bit of text description below. So Now, I set these 15 projects individually as a div.

▼this is one div▼

```
<div class="projects">
{image 2}<div grid-row="" grid-pad="0" grid-gutter="0">
    <div grid-col="x11" grid-pad="0" class="">
    <a href="example1" rel="history"><small>example,&nbsp;example</small><br>
</a></div>
    <div grid-col="x11" grid-pad="0" class=""><a href="example" rel="history"><b>example1 title,</b><br>
example description</a></div>
</div></div>
```

What I want to do is to pick 5 projects out of 15 projects, order shuffled.

Can anyone give me some hint?

Comment: Hint: read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: can you let us clearly know what you are expecting?

Comment: @user9405863 the goal is to pick 5 divs out of 15 divs, and shuffle the order when reloading the page